# Why delete method of JpaRepository does not actually remove elements from database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this two classes:

```
@Entity
public class Dinner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long dinnerId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dinner", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<DinnerTable> tables = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
public class DinnerTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long dinnerTableId;
    private int places;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dinner_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Dinner dinner;
```

If I execute this, it does not remove anything, even though it execute the deleteById method for each DinnerTable .

```
@Override
public void test1(String date) {
    Dinner dinner = dinnerService.getByDate(date);

    for(DinnerTable table: dinner.getTables()){
         dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(table.getDinnerTableId());
    }
}
```

Instead if I execute this method, it removed correctly the DinnerTable objects from the database.

```
@Override
public void test2(String date) {
    Dinner dinner = dinnerService.getByDate(date);

    dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(1);
    dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(2);
    dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(3);
}
```

These methods are inside this service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DinnerServiceImpl implements DinnerService {...}
```

And DinnerTableRepository is this class:

```
@Repository
public interface DinnerTableRepository extends JpaRepository<DinnerTable, Long> {
}
```

**EDIT**

This does not work either:

```
List<DinnerTable> tables = dinner.getTables();
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){           
    dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(tables.get(i).getDinnerTableId());
}
```

This works fine, it actually remove the DinnerTable objects from the database:

```
long id = 40;  //id of the first DinnerTable to remove
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(id + i);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This works:

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(43L, 44L, 45L));
for(Long id: ids){
    dinnerTableRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

**EDIT 3**

In this way it works:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dinner.getTables().size(); i++){
    dinner.removeTable(dinner.getTables().get(i));
}
dinnerRepository.save(dinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issues in `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`.

Furthermore, I'm using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) annotations

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
```

As I get it, Dinner-class is the main object and DinnerTable-class is dependent.

In this example I will use `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne` **bidirectional**.

[read this about cascade](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/)

Try this code:

#### Diner.java:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Dinner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dinner_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="dinner_generator", sequenceName = "dinner_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private long dinnerId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String date;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "professor",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<DinnerTable> tables = new ArrayList<>();

    /* 
    Use methods below to add or remove tables!!!!!!
    */

    public void addDinnertable(DinnerTable dinnerTable) {
        tables.add(dinnerTable);
        dinnerTable.setDinner(this);
    }

    public void removeDinnertable(DinnerTable dinnerTable) {
        tables.remove(dinnerTable);
        dinnerTable.setDinner(null);
    }
```

#### DinnerTable.java:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class DinnerTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dintable_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="dintable_generator", sequenceName = "dintable_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    private long dinnerTableId;

    private int places;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dinner_id")
    private Dinner dinner;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I'm not getting what is wrong with my implementation... can you please explain better what is going on?

Comment: @StefanoSambruna tell me which part is confusing you? P.S. Does my code works?

Comment: I still have to try but I don’t get it why it would... is it because of the wrong Ids annotations?

Comment: @StefanoSambruna No... I just decided to add for you "better" way of setting ID

Comment: Try first and later tell me results) If there would be any error - add here the longest line of a whole error

Comment: So if it’s not about the ids, what would make it work? Is identical to mine! I would like to understand, better than make it work. Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: I suppose that issue is in the way how you adding objects to DB. As you saw my entity - I have to methods for adding and removing objects. As soon as you add or removed object from `private List<DinnerTable> tables = new ArrayList<>();` - just save it to database and hibernate will automatically modify tables

Comment: @StefanoSambruna